# i can´t get the correct value using findminsearch in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have tried to follow the example in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html
 changing the banana function for this:

```
enter fun = @(x) x^2;
[x, fval] = fminsearch(fun, 1)
```

I expect to have a value of x = 0 but get "Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded" .

is there a way to get the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

this will help you and answers your question: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152034